CSS container width issue, doesn't play nice with "overflow"?
I believe this is my first time posting here.
I've been working in HTML and CSS on and off for 20+ years, but I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to modern HTML5 and CSS, so I don't know if this is me misunderstanding something or if it's a bug of some kind. (Probably the former.)
Here I have a mock-up of an interface layout. In general, it's supposed to be a full-screen interface (no scrolling), within which I want a menu panel that stretches across its container and scrolls horizontally.
<html>
    <style>
        .fullscreen { width: 100%; height:100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; margin: 0px; }
        .border { border: solid black 4px; padding: 8px; }
        .menuitem { display: inline-block; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: solid blue 1px; margin: 8px; }
    </style>
    <div class=fullscreen style="display: flex;"> <!-- full screen container-->
        <div style="padding: 8px; flex-grow: 1; display: flex;"> <!-- screen padding - doesn't play nice with fullscreen -->
            <div class=border style="min-width: 100px; margin-right: 8px;"></div> <!-- left menu -->
            <div class=border style="flex-grow: 1;"> <!-- right content container, grows to fill remaining space -->
                <div class=border style="max-width: 100%;"> <!-- intermediate container for the scrolling view, should be as wide as permissible -->
                    <div style="white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: auto; max-width: 100%;"> <!-- horizontally scrolling view -->
                        <!-- arbitrary contents of the scrolling view -->
                        <div class=menuitem></div>
                        <div class=menuitem></div>
                        <div class=menuitem></div>
                        <div class=menuitem></div>
                        <div class=menuitem></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>

The item of focus is the aforementioned scrolling view. I'm trying to limit its size to remain within its parent container, but it seems that its contents, although clipped, are causing the parent container to grow well off of the screen.
I've tried a variety of combinations of nesting containers, limiting sizes to varying amounts, etc.
One observation is that this only happens if I set the scrolling view to have a percentage max-width. If I specify a number of pixels, then it works as I would expect. This indicates to me that the layout size is calculated before the clipping of the scroll view occurs. I was hoping that the intermediate container (commented in the code) would help to fix that.
Similarly, if I change the scrolling view to have a much smaller percentage max-width (say, 10%), that div does indeed become smaller, but, bizarrely, the parent containers still behave as though the full width was present.
In short, a max-width set in pixels causes the parents to size as I would expect, but has unintuitive results when it's set to any percentage.
So, am I misunderstanding something about the concept of percent widths? Or perhaps there's a simple CSS attribute that will resolve this?

For making such layout, better use CSS Grid than basic styling.

As it turns out, yes, this is the saving grace for this and other issues I've been facing.

There are plenty of things that I'd change in your code. Let me put your code fixed first and then I'll explain what's wrong.
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .fullscreen { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; display: flex; }
  
  .border { border: solid black 4px; padding: 8px; }
  
  .menuitem { display: inline-block; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: solid blue 1px; margin: 8px; }
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    margin:0;
  }

  .outer-container {
    display: grid;
  }

  .inner-container {
    white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: auto; max-width: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="fullscreen"> <!-- full screen container-->
        <div style="flex-grow: 1; display: flex; gap: 8px; margin: 8px"> <!-- screen padding - doesn't play nice with fullscreen -->
            <div class="border" style="min-width: 100px;"></div> <!-- left menu -->
            <div class="border" style="flex-grow: 1;"> <!-- right content container, grows to fill remaining space -->
                <div class="border outer-container"> <!-- intermediate container for the scrolling view, should be as wide as permissible -->
                    <div class="inner-container"> <!-- horizontally scrolling view -->
                        <!-- arbitrary contents of the scrolling view -->
                        <div class="menuitem"></div>
                        <div class="menuitem"></div>
                        <div class="menuitem"></div>
                        <div class="menuitem"></div>
                        <div class="menuitem"></div>
                        <div class="menuitem"></div>
                        <div class="menuitem"></div>
                        <div class="menuitem"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>

First of all, I'd use absolute positioning as you are moving it to another z axis which is not needed in this case. Next, use vw/vh units in case you want to have always full device width and height (especially height can be quirky). Use gap instead of margin to make spaces between containers in flexbox (you've already used display: flex so you can make use of gap).
Finally, the main thing that solves your problem: display: grid.
The difference between flex and grid in simple words is the way they calculate the space for elements. The element with display: grid gives rules how children has to be drawn and how their dimensions need to be calculated, with flexbox it is kind of opposite. Children take what they need, so max-width in this case means take 100% of width that you need. In general to make it working as you want, you have to put any width that terminates calculation, so that's why pxs were also working - they have finite number.

Thank you very much for taking the time to correct it! Your explanation introduces several terms that are new to me, which I'll have to investigate further- namely grid, gap, and box-sizing. I'll try it out and I'll reply again once I have a better understanding of what each of these do.
Oh, one thing in the meantime: which element should use absolute positioning, and what did you mean by another z axis?

Just came back to say thanks again for your insight! I read up on the "grid" display, and it seems like this will help a whole lot going forward. (I only recently heard of "flex", too, so I wasn't quite sure of its proper application.) border-box is also a great thing to have learned; back in my day, we had to use nested padded divs to achieve this because of the inconsistencies between browsers. Glad they've solved that in the time since!

Yeah, I'd say it's a lot easier nowadays, I know what are you talking about ;) Absolute positioning is going out of regular 2d web page flow and you can use z-index to put elements in 3rd dimension (above or below other layers). It has to be used wisely. It can be used when an inner element has to be positioned in a container with disconnection to it's siblings (i.e. cross icon to close the pop-up), in such case parent element has to have position: relative.

enter image description here


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .fullscreen { 
            display: flex;
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100%; 
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0; 
            left: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
            padding: 8px; /* Adjusted to include the padding in fullscreen */
            box-sizing: border-box; /* Ensures padding is included in the width/height */
        }
        .border { 
            border: solid black 4px; 
            padding: 8px; 
            box-sizing: border-box; 
        }
        .menuitem { 
            display: inline-block; 
            width: 300px; 
            height: 300px; 
            border: solid blue 1px; 
            margin: 8px; 
        }
        .left-menu {
            min-width: 100px; 
            margin-right: 8px; 
        }
        .right-content {
            flex-grow: 1; 
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .scrolling-view {
            flex-grow: 1;
            white-space: nowrap; 
            overflow-x: auto; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fullscreen"> <!-- full screen container-->
        <div class="left-menu border"></div> <!-- left menu -->
        <div class="right-content border"> <!-- right content container, grows to fill remaining space -->
            <div class="scrolling-view border"> <!-- horizontally scrolling view -->
                <!-- arbitrary contents of the scrolling view -->
                <div class="menuitem"></div>
                <div class="menuitem"></div>
                <div class="menuitem"></div>
                <div class="menuitem"></div>
                <div class="menuitem"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



Try this code bro!

This is not even an answer. If I am not wrong understanding the question, he wants the scrollable components to stay within its parent container, the parent container should not grow beyond the page width and a horizontal scroll will work to show overflowed content


If you are trying to get result according to upper screenshot then apply this to container present below <!-- right content container, grows to fill remaining space -->
div.border { 
    width: 85vw;
}


Cool, thanks! That is approximately the result I want. However, if I understand correctly, there are two little shortcomings with it. The first is that it doesn't quite reach the right edge; I would prefer a solution that guarantees it exactly flush with the padding. And also, I'm not sure this is going to have the same results if the display size were to change, as the left column and padding amounts are not necessarily relative to viewport size.

@EdM If You want proper alignment of all component with using vw and vh then you have to replace all % with vw or vh. Also yes you will get same result on any display as it works with respect to viewport, you can try various screen size in inspect element. If you got your answer then accept it, it will be marked with green tick
